# kernel and Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The Frobenius map $f : F_{3^{18}}\to F_{3^{18}}$ is $F_3$-linear and has order $18$. The eigenvalues are $\pm1$. Also the ker$(f^2-I)$ is the field $F_{3^2}$, which is $2$-dimensional. Why does this imply that there is one $9 × 9$ Jordan block with eigenvalue $1$, and one $9 × 9$
Jordan block with eigenvalue $−1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the minimal polynomial of $f$ divides $X^{18}-1 = (X-1)^9\cdot (X+1)^9 \in \mathbb F_3[X]$, in particular the only possible eigenvalues are $\pm 1$. From $\dim \ker(f^2-I) = 2$, it follows that there are exactly two Jordan blocks. Clearly, $f(1) = 1\cdot 1$, i.e. $1$ is an eigenvalue. The polynomial $X^2+1\in \mathbb F_3[X]$ has a root $y$ in $\mathbb F_{3^2}\subseteq \mathbb F_{3^{18}}$. Hence $f(y) = y^3 = -y$, i.e. $-1$ is an eigenvalue. Let $n$ be the size of the Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. Then $18-n$ is the size of the Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$.
But since the minimal polynomial of $f$ divides $(X-1)^9\cdot (X+1)^9$, it follows that $n\le 9$ and $18-n\le 9$ and hence $n=9$. This is the assertion.

Comment: Why from dim ker$(f^2−I)=2$, it follows that there are exactly two Jordan blocks.?

Comment: $\dim \ker(f^2-I)=2$ tells you that the sum of *all* the eigenspaces has dimension 2. And the number of Jordan blocks equals the dimension of the sum of all the eigenspaces.